# Google sheets, vlookup, iferror formula in a script as a function

Tags: google-sheets, formula, vlookup, array-formulas

I have the below formula that populates data from another sheet into one of the columns.
The problem is that I have to allow access between the sheets for the below to work. Unfortunately with the IFERROR statement I don't see the "Allow access to the sheet" popup.
So i have to remove IFERROR and re-add it manually each time.

Is there a way to use vlookup without IFERROR?
Or could I put this formula as a function using the script ?

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(LOWER(IFERROR(IF(C1:C="test",VLOOKUP(A1:A,IMPORTRANGE("sheet_id","Master !L:N"),3,false),hosts!L3:L))))
```

many thanks

Answer (score 1):

**That is NOT the problem with your formula**. *(actually it seems to work just fine)*

The way the `IMPORTRANGE` function works is that **you only have to "Allow access ONCE**.

Once access is granted you don't have to do it again. The two sheets are connected for eternity :)

> ## **Tip:**

Instead of trying to grand access from inside your formula, try the following

On another cell (any empty cell will do) use just the `IMPORTRANGE` formula:

```
=IMPORTRANGE("sheet_id","Master !L:N")
```

You will be asked to give access. Allow it.
Now the sheets are connected and your formula works as expected.

Comment: Please share a demo sheet so you can be easier helped.

Comment: thanks marikamitsos, would you know how to wrap this into a function in a script and run it if necessary? thanks

Comment: _"The problem is that... I have to remove IFERROR and re-add it manually each time."_.  By the given answer your issue is solved. _"could I put this formula as a function using the script"_. This was thought as an alternative to your issue. Not necessary any more. Since the issue is resolved I would suggest you  [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) and create a new question about how to _"wrap this into a function in a script and run it"_ (which btw is a completely different thing and cannot be answered in the same answer).